# Android EditText cursor stay after left it

Tags: android

I have a problem on my Layout. In the layout you can find a lot of EditText.
When i click to edittext, than a popup dialog shows. But when I left the input, the cursor stay in.

[image: Five input, Five cursor. Why??]

All edittext have this settings:

```
editText.setFocusable(false);
editText.setClickable(true);
editText.setLongClickable(false);
editText.setTextIsSelectable(false);



 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_close_black_24dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />
```

How can I hide the cursor when i left the input field?

UPDATE:

Problem there is when i click to "RIGHT DRAWABLE" icon.

```
public static boolean isDrawableClick(MotionEvent event, EditText editText, DrawablePositions drawablePosition) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (editText.getCompoundDrawables()[drawablePosition.position] != null && event.getX() >= (editText.getRight() - editText.getLeft() - editText.getCompoundDrawables()[drawablePosition.position].getBounds().width())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden. Try this

Comment: I tried it,but it isn't work

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
setCursorVisible(false);
```

Comment: Any solution for "hide" it? When i click in, than I want to see the cursor

Comment: then you use setCursorVisible(true);

Comment: Ahh, change visible on every time? :| I think its have easier way

Comment: "How can I hide the cursor when i left the input field?" users usually do that by pressing the back button

Answer (score 0):

try this in your xml

```
 <EditText
  android:id="@+id/et_edit_account_birth_date"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:focusable="false"
  android:hint="@string/string_birth_date"
  />
```

and in your activity file

```
et_edit_account_birth_date.setCursorVisible(false);
```